# Парсинг DOM php

Tags: php, dom

Можно ли сохранить все теги выбраного узла? Для выбора есть только $elem->nodeValue  = только текст всех тегов. А можно ли получить все содержимое вместе с разметкой? Если нет, то как это сделать иным способом? спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть `DOMNode` (вы же `DOMDOcument` используете, правильно?) - то вам поможет метод [`saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.savehtml.php):

```
$html = $doc->saveHTML($myNode);
```

Однако учтите, что поддержка аргумента `$myNode` появилась с php5.3.6.

Аналог для XML - [`saveXML`](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.savexml.php).

Comment: Вы меня услышали) Благодарю за это. Ааааааа.... я знал о нем, и не подумал=( заклинило на том что его нужно использовать только в конце всего процесса) тупонул. Спасибо, глупостям нет предела)

Answer (score 1):

Есть два прекрасных инструмента, которые я использую:

- [Goutte / Guzzle Client](https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/goutte)
- [phpQuery](https://github.com/Coderockr/phpQuery)

  Для начала - создаете новый экземпляр класса GoutteClient или GuzzleClient и делаете дейтвия по порядку:

**Goutte**

```
$client = new Goutte\Client();

// Отправка запроса и получение контента в виде HTML
$content = $client->request('GET', 'http://stackoverflow.com/')->html();

// Достаем документ и создаем экземпляр синглтона дя  работы с phpQuery
$dom = phpQuery::newDocument('<!DOCTYPE html>' . $content);

// Крутим "барабан" со всеми элементами документа
foreach ($dom->find('*') as $element){
  // Инициализируем элемент как новый объект
  $element = pq($element);
  /**
   * И тут уже можно получать аттрибуты через
   * $element->attr('src') и т.д
   * $element->text()
   **/
}
```

**Guzzle**

```
$client = new Guzzle\Client();

$content = $client->get('http://stackoverflow.com/')->getBody()
->getContents();

$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($content);
```

, и остальное как и в предыдущем примере с Goutte.

Селекторы в *phpQuery* работают как и в нативном jQuery.

Comment: дайте пожалуйста мне простой ответ. С помощью этой штуки можно получить не текст узла, а всю разметку выбранного узла? А то вы написали как использовать ее, и все.

Comment: Это очень хорошо, но что первый что второй сводиться к выбору текста. Первый к получению значения атрибута, и текста элемента. - А мне нужен сам элемент с его атрибутами и текстом - я выбрал например родительский div (содержимое которого мне и должно возвращаться "<img src='image'/>" ) - так я хочу. Второй вариант вы просто по другому загружаете документ.

в DOM это можно сделать проще без превлечения библиотек.
    
$html = new DOMDocument();    
$html->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/')); 

Но спасибо.

Comment: @dimabuhayov, да - можно

Answer (score 0):

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ Попробуйде с помощью этой библиотеки. Она построена на селекторах по типу jquery, там можно выбрать html.

Comment: ответ не должен состоять только из одной ссылки, пожалуйста, приведите в ответе хотя бы один элементарный пример парсинга(код) при помощи simplehtmldom.

Comment: мне не нужны библиотеки, я и так их знаю все. Вы даете советы по тому как сделать парсинг более простым, предлагая "phpQuery", "Simple...". Вы не видите вопроса